# intento realizar consulta que abra distintos windowsforms c# y sqlite

Tags: c#, windows-forms, sqlite

este es el codigo
lo que quiero lograr es que se valide si hay registros en la base de datos y si hay que muestre una determinada ventana, el problema es que al presionar el boton de iniciar la ventana simplemente se cierra y el programa termina

como aqui se muestra si encuentra registros de usuarios en la tabla que abra la ventana para inicio de sesion, en cambio si no hay resgistros entonces que abra la ventana de crear usuario:

```
private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists("C:/Users/Usuario/source/repos/POS/POS/tienda.s3db"))
        {
            try
            {
                SQLiteConnection conexion = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = C:/Users/Usuario/source/repos/POS/POS/tienda.s3db");
                conexion.Open();
                string consul = "select * from Usuarios where id_usuario= 0 or id_usuario = 1";
                SQLiteCommand consulta = new SQLiteCommand(consul, conexion);
                consulta.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (consulta == null)
                {
                    crearnuevousuario ventana = new crearnuevousuario();
                    ventana.Show();
                    this.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    iniciarsesion ventana = new iniciarsesion();
                    ventana.Show();
                    this.Close();
                }
                conexion.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al conectar Base de datos" + error.Message);
            }
        }         
    }
```

Comment: Te salta algun error? En ese caso, que error te aparece? Sería de gran ayuda para poder decirte que puede estar pasando.

Comment: no, no hay errores, el programa tan solo termina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este problema es difícil de entender si no se sabe exactamente como funciona la creación de formularios en Windows Forms.

Los formularios se abren de forma jerárquica, de tal manera que en `Program.cs` se abre el primer formulario de la aplicación, y la aplicación acaba cuando este primer formulario es cerrado.

Lo que te está sucediendo es que estás lanzando un nuevo formulario (`crearnuevousuario` por ejemplo) desde el formulario inicial de la aplicación, para posteriormente cerrarlo. En el momento en el que cierras el formulario inicial, la aplicación finaliza.

Normalmente esto se debe a una estructura de la aplicación incorrecta. El formulario inicial debe estar siempre presente en una aplicación windows forms.

Como solución, lo mejor sería que en lugar de cerrar el formulario inicial, lo ocultaras (con Hide) y luego lo volvieras a mostrar, o acabaras la aplicación dependiendo del caso, cuando se cierre el formulario "hijo".

Te pongo un ejemplo de como podrías hacerlo:

```
this.Hide();
crearnuevousuario ventana= new crearnuevousuario();
ventana.FormClosed+= (s, args) => this.Close(); 
ventana.Show();
```

Como ves, primero ocultamos el formulario inicial. Luego creamos el nuevo formulario y nos suscribimos a su evento `FormClosed` para detectar cuando finaliza, y en ese momento cerramos el formulario inicial para cerrar la aplicación. Por último, mostramos el formulario hijo.

Comment: ya veo, muchas gracias!